# Visual Studio 2012 Extend F7 functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2012, single-page-application

We are working on a SPA application and we create an individual folder, index.js, index.less and index.html for each route (view). Please refer following figure.

[image]

Its over common requirement to switch between js,html, css within a specific folder like in older aspx we can open aspx.cs by pressing F7 and Shift+F7 vice versa.

How to develop/overwrite F7 kind of feature to switch between these three files.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can automatically groups these file tabs together and easily switch between them with the [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension (commercial, developed by me).